# ROS Answers SE migration: Jade vs Indigo

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm very new on ROS.
I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty).
I want to install ROS on my Linux.
Which ROS is the best for my OS..??
Jade, or Indigo, or maybe there is something better then those two..??

Thank you.

Regards,

Seano

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232003/jade-vs-indigo/) by [Seano](https://answers.ros.org/users/25807/seano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Indigo was made for Ubuntu 14.04 and is recommended for stability and more community support. You could also wait a bit and install ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 in May.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Seano](https://answers.ros.org/users/25807/seano/) on 2016-04-15**:
Get it..
Thanks for your answer.. :)

Seano